# DocumentDB: The specified data type value 'Point' is invalid.

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Getting the following exception on `DocumentClient.ReplaceDocumentCollectionAsync()`:

> Message: {"Errors":["The specified data type value 'Point' is invalid. Please choose between 'String' and 'Number' data types."]}

Code:

```
collection.IndexingPolicy.IncludedPaths.Add(new IncludedPath
{
    Path = "/*",
    Indexes = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Index>
        {
            new RangeIndex(DataType.String) { Precision = -1 },
            new RangeIndex(DataType.Number) { Precision = -1 },
            new RangeIndex(DataType.Point)
        }
});

Client.ReplaceDocumentCollectionAsync(collection).Wait();
```

Using `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB` 1.5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to set up a spatial index.

Try replacing:

```
new RangeIndex(DataType.Point)
```

with

```
new SpatialIndex(DataType.Point)
```

Comment: This is embarrassing. Thanks